# Truncating a int

Tags: python

Evening all,

I am curious as how you would "cut" an integer down. 
For example:

```
num = 12345678 
num_shrunk = "for example 3"(num)
print(num_shrunk)
123
```

I am aware of the round function however I need to be precise. I have tried format(num, "3d") however that is for decimal places. I also can't say only print num[0:3] as it isn't an integer.

Is there a simple way here of doing this that I am clearly not seeing?

Comment: One general algorithm that comes to mind is repeatedly dividing by 10 until the number is smaller than `10 ** num_shrunk` (= 1000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
N=3
int(str(num)[:N])
```

should do it ...

you could also do it mathematically

```
def nDigits(int_n):
    return nDigits(int_n//10) + 1 if int_n > 10 else 1
num//(10*(nDigits(num)-N)
# nDigits can also be caluclated as follows: numDigits = int(math.log(num,10))+1
```

although since you still need to convert it to a string to get the total number of digits

Comment: I thought about converting it into a string and doing that however once it has been processed I still need to do calculations on it and I would rather not have to re make it into a int as I am being marked as "less is more" sort of programming. Is there another way?

Comment: @APD remember that a truncation like you are describing is representation (read base10) specific. Coaxing an operation like this into a base agnostic mathematical formula is likely to be longer, more complex, and less efficient.

Comment: Thank you I have taken pointers from all the feedback and got something half working but im sure with a bit more fidderling I will get there. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one way to accomplish this in R by using modulus division:

```
> num <- 12345678
> numshrunk <- (num - num %% 100000) / 100000
> numshrunk
123
```

You can apply the same technique in python substituting the "<-" and "%%" for the appropriate variable assignment and modulus division operators respectively.

A more useful version of above:

```
> N = 3
> num <- 12345678
> numshrunk <- (num - num %% 10^(N-1)) / 10^(N-1)
> numshrunk
123
```

Comment: That is to say `=` and `%`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def shrink(number,amount=0): return number//(10**amount)
print shrink(1234,2)
```

should work as intended.
d//i is floor division and d**i is power multiplication. not giving an amount (shrink(5)) will return 5.